# Select column that may not exist without error, using standard evaluation

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to select a column that may or may not exist, and have it simply return all other columns if the column is missing with no error. This works in non-standard evaluation but not with standard evaluation with the tidyverse function `select_`.

For example, the following works as intended:

```
iris %>%
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, contains("banana"))

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1            5.1         3.5
2            4.9         3.0
3            4.7         3.2
4            4.6         3.1
...
```

But using standard evaluation (which I need to use to publish this in a package) this does not work:

```
iris %>%
  select_("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", contains("banana"))

Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
```

I realize what is wrong with the version that breaks, but I'm not sure what alternatives I have using tidyverse functionality.

Comment: I would avoid using `select` altogether in a package, the 1st version uses NSE, not the second one, why do you want to use `select_` ?

Comment: I think ? your terminology might be backward: i.e. `select()` uses NSE, while `select_` uses *standard* evaluation (i.e. non-NSE) ...

Comment: You can use strings in `select()` if that's the goal: `select("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", contains("banana"))`.  Also see `select_at()`.

Comment: Ben, my terminology is wrong. I meant using *standard* evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to leave the tidyverse, you can operate explicitly on the column names:

```
iris[intersect(names(iris), c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","banana"))]
```

For `contains()` you could use `grep`:

```
ccols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
           grep("banana", names(iris), value=TRUE))
iris[ccols]
```

This will still work (since it's *standard* evaluation) if you replace strings with variable references, i.e.:

```
x <- "banana"
ccols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
           grep(x, names(iris), value=TRUE))
iris[ccols]
```

Comment: I think you need `value = TRUE`